# how to remove Site Name proudly powered by Wordpress Entries(RSS) and Comments(RSS)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have developed my own custom theme for WordPress. Now recently I installed my theme under WordPress 3.9.1 and I have noticed a rather annoying message which appears on the second and third pages of my site. The message appears in the footer area. It does however not appear on the home page. The message conveyed is as following:

`site name proudly powered by Wordpress Entries(RSS) and Comments(RSS)`

Now one solution I have seen is to put the following into the `style.css`. however it does not work.

```
#site-generator{
   display:none;
}
```

The second solution is to modify the `footer.php` file and remove a block of php code, now interestingly enough my theme does not contain a `footer.php` file. Just wondering is it some WordPress system file pushing out the message on my theme.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: That would typically be output by one of the WordPress standard themes. Did you base your custom theme on one of the standard WordPress themes? If so, which one? Do you remember a "credits" action in any of the footer files? (And which template are the second and third pages using? Just page.php?)

Comment: No the theme I developed was from scratch. I did not use any other wordpress theme as a template or otherwise. the theme files are as such index.php,page.php sidebar1.php,sidebar2.php,sidebar3.php and function.php and i entered the php code into all the mentioned php files so i know what in there. I feel myself wordpress 3.9.1 is stuffing my theme somehow can't explain why though.

Comment: Have you tried deactivating all plugins to see if one of those is injecting it somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

If you call [`get_footer()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_footer) anywhere in your theme, but your theme doesn't include a footer.php, then a footer template is provided for you automatically:

> [If the theme contains no footer.php file then the footer from the default theme wp-includes/theme-compat/footer.php will be included.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_footer)

This "theme compatibility" footer outputs a standard footer which includes the lines:

```
<?php printf(__('%1$s is proudly powered by %2$s'), get_bloginfo('name'),
'<a href="https://wordpress.org/">WordPress</a>'); ?>
<br /><?php printf(__('%1$s and %2$s.'), '<a href="' . get_bloginfo('rss2_url') . '">' . __('Entries (RSS)') . '</a>', '<a href="' . get_bloginfo('comments_rss2_url') . '">' . __('Comments (RSS)') . '</a>'); ?>
```

Which I'm pretty sure is where your "site name proudly powered by Wordpress Entries(RSS) and Comments(RSS)" will be coming from.

So, check your theme files for "get_footer()". If you don't have a `footer.php`, then you probably don't want to be using that.

**However**, it would be normal to include a `footer.php` so you can have standard footer code across all pages, for doing vital things like calling [`wp_footer()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer) on every page, which is something you *must* do in a theme.

`wp_footer` is a standard hook point for plugins, themes, and WordPress itself to inject scripts, and anything else necessary, just before the closing of the HTML body, `</body>`. It's how the admin menubar gets output, for example, and often plugin Javascript. So you absolutely want it called at the bottom of every template, and providing a `footer.php` that does this (and closes your `<body>` and `<html>` tags, etc.) and including it from all of your template pages with `get_footer()` is the normal way.

If your current code works well and produces valid HTML while using the standard "compatibility" `get_footer()`, then personally, I'd add the bare minimum `footer.php` to your own theme:

```
        <?php wp_footer(); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS should probably say something more along the lines of

```
.site-generator {
    display: none;
}
```

or if that doesn't work you could always do

```
.site-generator {
    display: none!important;
}
```

What you have is missing the '.' which refers to the class 'site-generator'. It might also be an ID, in which case, it should look like

```
#site-generator {
    display: none;
}
```

If you'd rather remove it from the theme, you could let me know what theme you're using, and I can take a look at where it is occurring in the theme.

Comment: Hi Dylan, Yes I have tried all of the above and to no avail. The proudly powered by is still there most annoying. Please note I did create this theme from scratch myself no other wordpress themes involved here. So as per my comment above I know all the php files involved in this theme and coded all the files. At most there is about 10 lines of code in the most complex php file in my theme. it's a very simple theme but effective none the less

Comment: Then it may very well be a plugin that you have installed that is adding it in. If that's the case, you'll have to figure out the CSS rules that plugin is setting, and set something of a higher precedence.

Comment: This method is not recommended due to SEO reasons. Even though search engines should ignore non-displayed text, they haven't gotten around to it and instead punish all because some use it to hide search words that will game the search engine. Not a pretty future.

Answer (score 0):

I know this can be done only by making some changes on the file `footer.php`.If you can't find the footer.php file, look for another PHP file with "foot" or "footer" in the filename.

Just see a detailed explanation [here](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/change-footer-credits-wordpress-50776.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using a footer.php file, the footer info must be in the bottom of index.php and page.php.  My hunch is that the generator was removed from your page file, but not the index file. I would check that file and make sure the code isn't there.

If that doesn't work, you need to see what the css selector is surrounding the generator.  If you right click on the sentence within your browser, you should get some sort of 'inspect element' option.  (I use Chrome, but other browsers have similar tools.)  Inspect the element and you should see some sort of class or id to target.  It may be a

```
<div id="example">
```

or

```
<p class="example">
```

Find the id or class and modify your css, i.e.:

for an id:

```
#example {
    display: none;
}
```

or for a class:

```
.example {
    display: none;
}
```

If the generator is being added by an external source you may need to add !important.

```
.example {
    display: none!important;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Heytricia Solved it!! as per your css examples I viewed the source of the offending page and noticed a <div id="footer"> so in my css file I included your example for an id above #footer{display:none;} and this solved it many thanks

Comment: Glad to help, but this may not be a good long-term fix for you.  Hiding the whole footer could come back to haunt you later.  I had thought you could hide just one element within the footer and move on.  If, as @MattGibson has shown, WP is generating it's own footer when called, you would definitely be better off creating your own footer.php file and controlling what gets generated that way.

Answer (score 0):

Another route would be copy the footer.php file in your theme's directory and paste it into a child theme. Open up the footer.php file in your child theme and delete the text with the sitename and powered by. It should be wrapped in php tags.

Answer (score 0):

Easy! If your theme doesn't have a footer.php file (for example if you are creating a theme from scratch), create it and leave it empty. It will just disapear the annoying "proudly powered by..."

Example of theme/:

```
style.css  // theme info
header.php // empty file <----
footer.php // empty file <----
index.php  // file with wordpress loop, etc.
```

Answer (score -1):

you can edit your theme in admin panel, (footer.php)
if you see an error on your homepage when you edit the footer.php you can use javascript to delete that. But first you should add  tag with an id, then access that id in javascript like;

```
function myFunc(){
document.getElementById('id').innerHTML ="";
}
```

then edit your body tag like

```
<body onload="myFunc()">
```